# Error while working with dates in pl/sql?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

This is how it's supposed to work:
I have a table called Pro2 with a column called finall that is a date and another one called validade. If finall has already happened or is happening validade is set to 0.

```
BEGIN
     FOR validade in (SELECT * FROM PRO2 WHERE TRUNC(finall)<= TRNCU(SYSDATE))
     LOOP
     SET validade = 0
     END LOOP;
END;
```

I'm new in PL/SQL please help!

Comment: What kind of error is shown from the db? Consider update your question.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your second `TRUNC` command.

You aren't supposed to set `validade` (which is a `CURSOR`) to any value.

Assignment operator is `:=` and not `SET` in PL/SQL.

Try this:

```
BEGIN
     FOR r_record IN (SELECT * 
                        FROM PRO2 
                       WHERE TRUNC(finall) <= TRUNC(SYSDATE))
     LOOP
         UPDATE PRO2 t1
            SET t1.validade = 0
          WHERE t1.id = r_record.id;
     END LOOP;
END;
```

You shouldn't use PL/SQL for such thing!

**Use SQL when it is possible!**

```
UPDATE PRO2
   SET validade = 0
 WHERE TRUNC(finall) <= TRUNC(SYSDATE);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help , but it's still doesn't run.

Comment: it gives invalid identifiers in r_record and id and and a statement ignored in update pro2 t1. SQL works but unfortunately I really have to do it in PL/SQL and I just don't get it

Answer (score 0):

Every well-designed Oracle table has a primary key, often called **id** or ending with it. That is what Alex meant  by t1.id. You should ask for the column(-combination) that makes the primary key for PRO2 and substitute that.

DML code like the shown UPDATE can be included in PLSQL and is really the best solution:

```
BEGIN
   -- other things here ....
   UPDATE pro2
      SET validade  = 0
    WHERE TRUNC( finall ) <= TRUNC( SYSDATE );
-- and here ...
END;
```

Comment: I actually settled with this solution, the problem is it won't run when I use it in Java. It only runs when I remove begin and end, and like that it's not PL/SQL. And my problem is that it HAS to be in PLSQl.

Comment: @InêsFidalgo You need to update your question to include all this information